# Open-cv haar trainer app

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier

i am trying to train a **classifier** of an object.
 I have tried to train it in **MATLAB** and i am getting good results.
 But the generated output *.xml* file can't be used in **open-cv**.
 so can anyone tell me how can i use the **MATLAB** generated *.xml* file in **open-cv** or can anyone give me some **link** to app where i can directly put my positive and negative images and it can do all the training and give me out **.xml** file in *open-cv*.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://tutorial-haartraining.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/HaarTraining/bin/) you can find several *.exe* that will help you to train your OpenCV classifier.

And [here](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) you can find a tutorial. Hope it helps!